# Clustering 16 million records in parallel

Tags: time-limit-exceeded, r, clustering, machine-learning, geospatial

I have a dataset with 16 million rows and may increase upwards of 30 million. I am using the `parLapply` to run across three cores in R. But it's taking two days to run to completion. When I try smaller datasets of about 60,000 it takes less than 5 minutes to run, what may be cause of this disparity.

Desktop Specs : Corei5 -QuadCore , 4GB RAM

FG DataSet (16 million rows)

```
"Id","R","T"
"1","12","43963"
"2","12","50273"
"3","12","40805" 
"4","13","50273"
"5","13","40805"
"6","14","40805"
```

AB (1.3 million rows)

```
"Id","R",
"1","12"   
"2","13"
"3","14"   
"4","15"
```

Locations (6600 rows)

```
T,NEWLong,NEWLat,SITENAME,
43963,-77.108995,17.942062,HARBOUR TOWN
50273,-77.108995,17.942062,NEW MEADOWS
40805,-77.108995,17.942062,ISLE AVENUE
```

---

Code

```
num_cores = detectCores() -1
cl = makeCluster(num_cores)
clusterExport(cl,varlist = c("FG","AB","sites","distancematrix")
              ,envir=environment())

results = parLapply(cl,1:nrow(AB),function(i){
  row = AB[i,2]
  filtered = subset(FG,FG$R == AB[i,2])
  sites = merge(filtered , locations , by.x = "T" , by.y = "T" , all.x = FALSE)
  resultdf =unique(data.frame(sites$NAME,sites$NEWLong,sites$NEWLat))

    if ((nrow(resultdf))==0)
   {

    VAL = data.frame("AN" = AB[i,2] ,"SCORE" = 0 ,"SITES" = 0,"DISTANCE" = 0)
   }
  else if ((nrow(resultdf) > 0) & (nrow(resultdf) < 4))
  {

  alldistance = round(distanceMatrix(resultdf))
  VAL2 = data.frame("AN" = AB[i,2] ,"SCORE"= 1 ,"SITES" =       nrow(resultdf),"DISTANCE"=sum(alldistance))
   }
   else if ((nrow(resultdf) >= 4) & (nrow(resultdf) <= 10 ))
  {

  alldistance = round(distanceMatrix(resultdf))
  if (sum(alldistance) == 0)
  {
    VAL = data.frame("AN" = AB[i,2] ,"SCORE"= 1 ,"SITES" = nrow(resultdf),"DISTANCE"=sum(alldistance))
  }
  else
  {
    value = nrow(resultdf)-1
    require(fpc)
    clustervaluePAMK = pamk(alldistance,krange = 1:value, criterion = "asw" ,critout = TRUE , usepam=FALSE, ns = 2)
    clustervaluePAMK  = clustervaluePAMK$nc
    VAL2 = data.frame("AN" = AB[i,2] ,"SCORE"= clustervaluePAMK ,"SITES" = nrow(resultdf),"DISTANCE"=sum(alldistance))

  }

}
else 
{
  alldistance = round(distanceMatrix(resultdf))
  if (sum(alldistance) == 0)
  {
    VAL = data.frame("AN" = AB[i,2] ,"SCORE"= 1 ,"SITES" =     nrow(resultdf),"DISTANCE"=sum(alldistance))
  }
  else
  {
    require(fpc)
    clustervaluePAMK = pamk(alldistance,krange = 1:10, criterion = "asw" ,critout = TRUE , usepam=FALSE, ns = 2)
    clustervaluePAMK  = clustervaluePAMK$nc
    VAL = data.frame("AN" = AB[i,2] ,"SCORE"= clustervaluePAMK ,"SITES" = nrow(resultdf),"DISTANCE"=sum(alldistance))

  }

}

})
```

{FGL <- merge(FG, locations) }) and object.size(FGL)

```
 user  system elapsed 
 393.70   10.24  993.51 

656225664 bytes
```

Code Profile
--For this section I ran against 60,000 elements.

```
$by.self
               self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
"unserialize"     174.70    99.99     174.70     99.99
"as.character"      0.02     0.01       0.02      0.01

$by.total
                     total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
"clusterApply"           174.72    100.00      0.00     0.00
"do.call"                174.72    100.00      0.00     0.00
"lapply"                 174.72    100.00      0.00     0.00
"parLapply"              174.72    100.00      0.00     0.00
"staticClusterApply"     174.72    100.00      0.00     0.00
"unserialize"            174.70     99.99    174.70    99.99
"FUN"                    174.70     99.99      0.00     0.00
"recvData"               174.70     99.99      0.00     0.00
"recvData.SOCKnode"      174.70     99.99      0.00     0.00
"as.character"             0.02      0.01      0.02     0.01
"cut"                      0.02      0.01      0.00     0.00
"cut.default"              0.02      0.01      0.00     0.00
"factor"                   0.02      0.01      0.00     0.00
"split"                    0.02      0.01      0.00     0.00
"split.default"            0.02      0.01      0.00     0.00
"splitIndices"             0.02      0.01      0.00     0.00
"splitList"                0.02      0.01      0.00     0.00
"structure"                0.02      0.01      0.00     0.00

$sample.interval
[1] 0.02

$sampling.time
[1] 174.72
```

Comment: @flodel added runtime

Comment: @flodel I might have to rethink that sections as to see if there is a better way to process the data. Might have to do it in chunks  or make use of some of the bigmemory library and see what happens

Comment: For large data, `data.table` is sooo much faster than regular data frames.

Comment: @flodel I am already doing a premerge since working with the data tables are much quicker and using setkeys to allow for faster search. All this happens out side the loop.

Comment: I have rolled back the question to Rev 4. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard to tell without sample data, but lets start with a cleaned up
version as there's *soo much* duplicated code here and the formatting is
inconsistent.

- The `require` should probably go to the top?
- `AB[i, 2]`, `nrow(resultdf)` are run more than once and that's not
  good.
- Some expressions are the same in multiple branches and can be merged,
  e.g. `alldistance = ...` and `sum(alldistance)`.
- AFAIK `parLapply` just uses the return value of the function, so the
  assignments to `VAR` and `VAR2` are super confusing.

All refactored that looks like this now, which almost fits into a single
screen now:

```rlang
require(fpc)

cl = makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
clusterExport(cl, varlist = c("FG", "AB", "sites", "distancematrix"), envir = environment())

results = parLapply(cl, 1:nrow(AB), function(i) {
  row = AB[i, 2]
  filtered = subset(FG, FG$R == row)
  sites = merge(filtered, locations, by.x = "T", by.y = "T", all.x = FALSE)
  resultdf = unique(data.frame(sites$NAME, sites$NEWLong, sites$NEWLat))

  n = nrow(resultdf)

  if (n == 0)
  {
    data.frame("AN" = row, "SCORE" = 0, "SITES" = 0, "DISTANCE" = 0)
  }
  else
  {
    alldistance = round(distanceMatrix(resultdf))
    s = sum(alldistance)

    if (n < 4 || s == 0)
    {
      score = 1
    }
    else
    {
      score = pamk(alldistance, krange = 1:min(n - 1, 10), criterion = "asw", critout = TRUE, usepam = FALSE, ns = 2)$nc
    }

    data.frame("AN" = row, "SCORE" = score, "SITES" = n, "DISTANCE" = s)
  }
})
```